# why I get this error in MATLAB? Undefined function or variable 'readmatrix'

Tags: matlab

I have a file which is a data set and I want to make a matrix with this :

```
A = readmatrix(filename)
```

why I get this error:

```
  Undefined function or variable 'readmatrix'.

  Error in untitled13 (line 3)
  A = readmatrix('t2.csv')
```

Notice than the spell of everything has  been checked many times!

Comment: Function introduced in R2019a. What version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Use `dlmread` instead. You can read more about this function here: [dlmread](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html#mw_cc1fb06c-a957-435b-b997-76000fa1dd04). My guess is that you are using the older version of Matlab (2018 and prior).

The function `readmatrix` is only available in version 2019 (and later).